# How to publish asp.net web site to azure when not an asp.net web project

Tags: azure, publishing, visual-studio-2012

Using Visual Studio 2012 RC, I have many existing asp.net (VB) web sites and I always simply select open web site when I edit them in VS, they are not web projects.

I want to publish some of them now to my azure account, but if I simply right click the solution and select publish web site I dont get the same publish options as I do if it was a web project? I get the default publish option asking me where I want to place my compiled pages.

How can I import the publish settings for my azure web site for web sites?

I don't want to have to convert all web sites to projects.

Answer (score 1):

Windows Azure Web Sites allow you to deploy your website in different ways, including TFS, Git, ... But in your case it might be interesting to look at **FTP deployment**. This because, when right clicking on a web site you can choose to copy the website:

[image: Copy Website]

The copy feature allows you to copy the website to an FTP server.

[image: Copy to FTP]

The information to access your web site through FTP can be found on the [dashboard](https://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/manage/services/web-sites/how-to-manage-websites/).